# sending data from html form to SQLite database using python/flask

Tags: python, database, forms, sqlite, flask

I am trying create a registration program where guests can register and their inf will be saved in a database.

I already created my form and database.
The only thing I get stuck on is sending the user input from the form to the database.

My HTML code:

```
{% block body %}

<form action="{{ url_for('my_form') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Gasten registratie</h1>
        <p>Vul dit formulier in om te registreren</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="First-Name"><b>Voornaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="First-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" name="Voornaam" required>

        <label for="Last-Name"><b>Achternaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Last-Name" placeholder="Vul hier uw achternaam in" name="Achternaam" required>


        <label for="Company-name"><b>Bedrijfsnaam</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="Company-name" placeholder="Vul hier uw bedrijfsnaam in" name="Bedrijfsnaam" required>


        <label for="Date"><b>Datum</b></label>
        <input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Selecteer de Datum" name="Datum" required />
        <hr>


        <p>In het kader van onze ISAE certificering registreren wij uw gegevens.</p>
        <p>Wij verwerken uw gegevens volgends de regels van het AVG.</p>
        <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Registreren</button>
    </div>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3 
from sqlite3 import Error

app = Flask(__name__) 

# hier maak ik de db aan en een connectie
def create_connection(db_file):
    connection = None;
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn 

# hier roep ik de functie voor de db aan en maak ik een db file "gast.db"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection("gast.db") 

# hier maak ik de table aan voor de db (moet ik nog aanpassen voor sqlite3)

def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

def main():
    database = r"gast.db"

    sql_create_guests_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guests (
                                        id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                        voor_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        achter_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        bedrijfs_naam text NOT NULL,
                                        datum date NOT NULL

                                    ); """

    conn = create_connection(database)

    if conn is not None:
        # maak gast table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_guests_table)

    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# hier zorg ik ervoor dat 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


# hier zorg ik ervoor dat de input uit het formulier naar de db gaat
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        guest_vnaam = request.form['Voornaam']
        guest_anaam = request.form['Achternaam']
        guest_cnaam = request.form['Bedrijfsnaam']
        guest_datum = request.form['Datum']

        safe_vnaam = guests(voor_naam=guest_vnaam)
        safe_anaam = guests(achter_naam=guest_anaam)
        safe_cnaam = guests(bedrijfs_naam=guest_cnaam)
        safe_datum = guests(datum=guest_datum)

        try:
            db.session.add(safe_vnaam)
            db.session.add(safe_anaam)
            db.session.add(safe_cnaam)
            db.session.add(safe_datum)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens'

    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

# hier run ik de app 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If someone could help in the right direction, that would be great!
Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Ronny

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `guest_vnaam = request.form.get('Voornaam')` instead of  `guest_vnaam = request.form['Voornaam']`.

`c = conn.cursor()` add that right under your first if statement. You will need that to save the data in your database.

And this piece of code will save it in your database

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO database.table (columnName,columnName) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
c.execute(sql,(guest_vnaam, guest_anaam, guest_cnaam,  guest_datum))
connection.commit()
```

So your code will look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        c = conn.cursor()
        guest_vnaam = request.form.get('Voornaam')
        guest_anaam = request.form.get('Achternaam')
        guest_cnaam = request.form.get('Bedrijfsnaam')
        guest_datum = request.form.get('Datum')

        try:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO databasename.tablename (columnName,columnName,columnName,columnName) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
            c.execute(sql,(guest_vnaam, guest_anaam, guest_cnaam,  guest_datum))
            connection.commit() 
            #or "conn.commit()" (one of the two)
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Er ging iets fout met het opslaan van uw gegevens'
```

I hope this will help you :)

And a tip, always program in English not in Dutch :P

Comment: Thanks for your first answer ! Please note that using .get may insert NULLs in the database by getting None from the get. Maybe some kind of valisation is needed instead, and throwing an exception can be valid there if those names are not nullable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it. And will be programming in English in the future (;

Comment: Hi, I tried running the script with the new changes, but I get a error...

Comment: This is the error: 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 402 supplied.

the code is the same, I only changes the part you suggested... I have no clue what the error means

Comment: It was probably a problem because I made a spelling mistake. I have edited it now. maybe that will work. I had put an unnecessary word next to columName it was 'ci' or so(i have deleted that no), maybe the problem was there.